# Node.js with Express, Jest and SuperTest never fail

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, tdd, supertest

I'm new in Jest and TDD. Please, help me!
I'm using supertest to request the API, but even with the server turned off, the tests never fail. I've tried use return or async await and it not solved

I have the following structure at Node.js project:

```
nodemodules
src
    controllers
        users-controller.js
    index.js
    routes.js
    server.js
test
    user.test.js
package.json
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint src/** test/** --fix",
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "jest-watch": "jest --watch"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.3.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
},
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
}
```

src/server.js:

```
const app = require('./index')

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port 3001')
})
```

src/index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(routes)

module.exports = app
```

src/routes.js

```
const routes = require('express').Router()
const UserController = require('./controllers/users-controller')

routes.get('/', (req, res) => { res.status(200).send() })
routes.get('/users', UserController.findAll)
routes.post('/users', UserController.create)

module.exports = routes
```

src/controllers/user-controller.js

```
module.exports = {
    findAll(req, res) {
        const users = [
            { name: 'John Doe', mail: 'john@mail.com' }
        ]
        return res.status(200).json(users)
    },

    create(req, res) {
        return res.status(201).json(req.body)
    }
}}
```

test/user.test.js:

```
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../src/index')


test('Should list users', () => {
    return request(app).get('/users')
        .then(res => {
            expect(res.status).toBe(200)
            expect(res.body).toHaveLength(1)
            expect(res.body[0]).toHaveProperty('name', 'John Doe')
        })
})

test('Should insert a user', async () => {
    await request(app).post('/users')
        .send({ name: 'Walter Mitty', email: 'walter@mail.com' })
        .then(res => {
            expect(res.status).toBe(201)
            expect(res.body.name).toBe('Walter Mitty')
        })
})
```

And the result is always the same:

```
PASS  test / user.test.js
✓ Should list users. (16ms)
✓ Should insert a user. (13ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests: 2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots: 0 total
Time: 0.456s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Comment: Hello! What of those tests should fail and why?

Comment: Hello, andresmunozit! All of them. The server (Express) is off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see what the problem is, although isn't really a problem, is the normal behavior of Jest and Supertest. I'll explain to you. If Express app isn't listening, it doesn't affect the Jest or Supertest behavior. Why? Just because the `app` that you pass to supertest `request(app)` runs an independent process of the app, and when the tests are finished, that app finishes too. In other words, Supertest runs the Express app on a different process, do the tests, and finishes that process.

This test will fail if you expect another response code, for example 400. The following test should fail for sure:

```
test('Should list users', async () => {
    // First assertion
    const response = await request(app)
        .get('/users')
        .send()
        .expect(400) // This will make fail, because the app instance running for test, is working just fine and will return 200, if you expect a different code, so the test will fail

    // Second assertion
    expect(response.body[0]).toHaveProperty('name', 'John Doe')
})
```

So that is the normal behavior of Jest and Supertest. It runs the Express app, just for running the tests, in another independent process. It doesn't matter if your Express main process is still running or if it's stopped.

Comment: Didn't work, @andresmunozit. I left only one test with your refactoring suggestion, and the behavior was exactly the same. The console.log show the array: [ { name: 'John Doe', mail: 'john@mail.com' } ].

Comment: I've edited my answer trying to be correct and clear enough. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Wow, forgive me. I think I was not very clear. I'm using supertest to make the request to the server. Even with the server turned off, the status returned is still 200. The test doesn't fail.

Comment: When you run the test script `npm run test`, Jest runs and just use the app exported in `src/index.js`, runs the tests on it and stops. When you say "Express is not running", you are saying that this script `"start": "node src/server.js"` is not running, but it doesn't matter. Jest runs on a differnt script, hence on a different independent process, do the tests and exit. Jest doesn't need that the `start` script is running to do his task, becaus it do it on a different process, even it uses a different script.

Comment: In the website of Jest, it says it clearly"isolated 

Tests are parallelized by running them in their own processes to maximize performance" https://jestjs.io/en/

Comment: Now I understand what is happening, @andresmunozit! Thank you! To confirm your explanation, I made a change by passing "http://localhost:3001" as a parameter for the supertest. This change had the behavior that I, erroneously, was expecting the supertest to have with the app. Again, thank you very much, my friend!

Comment: I'm glad to help. By the way, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.